# Rounding average getting progressively worse

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to average a reading from an altitude sensor with an Arduino, but over time the resolution gets worse and worse, although the raw input data stays the same.

All the variables that are not explicitly defined in this code are float.

```
altTotal = 0.00;
slopeTotal = 0.00;

altitude = ps.readFloatAltitudeMeters();

//=========== Altitude averaging
for (int j = 0.00; j <=(aveNum-2); j++) {
  arrAlt[j] = arrAlt[j+1];
}

arrAlt[aveNum-1] = altitude;

for (i = 0.00; i <= (aveNum-1); i++){
  altTotal = altTotal + arrAlt[i];
}

altAve = altTotal/(i);
//============

f = f+1;
altRd = altRd + altAve;

if (f == 5) {

//======== check cycle time
unsigned long endCycle = micros();
unsigned long delta = endCycle - start;
delta = delta/1000;
unsigned long start = endCycle;


loop1 = loop2;
loop2 = delta;
loopTime = loop2-loop1;
//========

  v0 = v1;
  v1 = v2;
  v2 = altRd/f - v0 - 2*v1;
  altButt = v0 + 2*v1 + v2;

  alt1 = alt2;
  alt2 = altButt;
  climbRate = (alt2 - alt1) * (1000/loopTime); //to convert climb rate to m/s

  //climbRate = -5;

  f = 0;
  altRd = 0;

}
```

I expect the output of "climbRate" to have a consistent resolution, but over time, the resolution get worse, in multiples of two. First it starts with a resolution of 0.006, then 0.012, then 0.023 then 0.047, then 0.094 etc.

Here is an example of the output:

```
0.000,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,0.00m altRd ,1603.11m altButt
0.000,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,1603.12m altRd ,1603.11m altButt
0.000,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,3206.23m altRd ,1603.11m altButt
0.000,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,4809.35m altRd ,1603.11m altButt
0.000,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,6412.46m altRd ,1603.11m altButt
0.023,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,0.00m altRd ,1603.12m altButt
0.023,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,1603.12m altRd ,1603.12m altButt
0.023,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,3206.24m altRd ,1603.12m altButt
0.023,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,4809.37m altRd ,1603.12m altButt
0.023,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,6412.51m altRd ,1603.12m altButt
0.047,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,0.00m altRd ,1603.13m altButt
0.047,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,1603.14m altRd ,1603.13m altButt
0.047,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,3206.28m altRd ,1603.13m altButt
0.047,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,4809.42m altRd ,1603.13m altButt
0.047,m/s ,0,0.10,328ms ,6412.55m altRd ,1603.13m altButt
```

I am not sure where the problem comes in.

I had some of the variables as different types, but I turned all of them into floats to try and increase the resolution but no success.

Comment: Can you please produce a [mcve]? This has too much of unrelated code.

Comment: Edited the question to show the output as well. The code that I posted forms part of a much larger system, this is just a part of a function. Will see if I can create a reproducible example. The decrease in resolution happens over time, as in minutes, not instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you where exactly is the error, given the example above, but I can tell you what causes the issue and what to look for to fix it.

Your code is numerically unstable. Real values are expressed via [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) in C++ as in most other languages (there is a new more accurate standard being introduced but it is not widely available).

`float` has 23 bits for value precision, meaning its accuracy is about 10^{-7} of its value. Everything below that is being truncated.

For example: `2e7f + 1 == 2e7f` is `true` because is 1 too small given precision of floating point.

Most likely somewhere in your code you take a difference of two increasingly large floating point variables resulting with their difference having less and less accuracy over time.

To fix it, you can work with `double` instead of `float`. If you cannot, or it is not sufficient then you have to make your code more stable numerically... it can be complicated... it is not something that can be easily explained within a short answer. Seek tutorials on the issue.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for the answer. I will try a couple things, and report back on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So my code is indeed numerically unstable. The source of it is the large numbers, with many decimals that eventually just get truncated in calculations. I cannot change any of the numbers to make them smaller, as I need to use the whole range. So instead of re-architecting the solution, I just applied the following fix:

Once per minute I just reset all the numbers that cause the problem to zero. The small inaccuracy I get it negligible, and my code stays accurate to three decimals (I tested it for 24 hours and it is working perfectly fine).

Thanks for the assistance.